# Error in the executable file while opening a dat file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, face-recognition, dlib

I have made a face recognition system. Now i converted it to an execuable file using the pyinstaller. It is based on the `dlib shape_predicter_68..dat` file. But it is unable to load the open the `dat file`.It is giving this error. The dat file is authentic because the code is running errorless.

```
RuntimeError: Unable to open /tmp/_MEIs1nfPB/face_recognition_models/models/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
[50636] Failed to execute script 'Application' due to unhandled exception!
```

I tried all the thing like giving the absolute path of the file. Bundlling it together with the python file but still it is unable to open the `dat file`.